# Why some Ruby constants (classes, modules) should be explicitly required in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There seems to be two types of classes in ruby, one type I don't need to require they're always accessible (like Float, Array, Hash, etc.). They are a part of ruby and this is expected.

But there are also some constants that are not accessible unless explicitly required (like [REXML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML.html), [Observable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html), [YAML](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)). They are part of Ruby too and I would expect to be able to access them without require.

Why these constants are not available without require?

In Rails guides it is not recommended to explicitly require anything as this messes up Rails autoload mechanism. If these constants need to be required anyway, what is the best way to do it?

Should I use **require** or **require_dependency**?

Should I use require at the top of the file where the constant is used or should I do it globally somehow?

EDIT: Also, since constants availability depends on the loading order it is easy to forget to require some file and it will not break until load order changes somehow. What is the best way to not face such error except being extra alert about every constant you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of things that are "built-in".

1. Ruby core. These things you don't have to require. They're part of the language itself. Array, Hash, etc.
2. Standard library (stdlib). Things like Struct, OpenStruct, additional functionality of Time, etc. They are not essential to the language. Just functionality that is available to you. If you don't use, say, REXML in your program, it doesn't need to be loaded (which would be waste of CPU time and memory). So, you have to require these things prior to using them.

> If these constants need to be required anyway, what is the best way to do it?

If you don't monkeypatch them, then you just go ahead and require them whereever you want. I normally do it at the top of the file where they are used.

If you do monkeypatch them, I suggest you reconsider. :)

Comment: Ok, that is fine, I can require them at the top. But consider the next situation: I use the constant in multiple files. So I should require it in each file at the top. But ruby does not enforce me to do that, if one file has already been loaded all files that are loaded after it can use the constant.

The problem is that I can easily forget to require the file if it works without require and the if the load order changes it'll break.

Comment: @LevDenisov: this introduces load order dependency. Don't do that. Either require the thing in a boot file or in each individual file that uses it.

Comment: @LevDenisov: once I spent two days debugging exactly this: mysterious error which originated from something being loaded in one case and not loaded in another.

Comment: Exactly, I see problem with it, but I see no way to get around it except of being paranoid about every constant I use.

Another way would be require them in some file like application.rb but it seems weird too

Comment: Not sure I see the big problem here. If we're talking rails, then all gems are required by default. So you don't have to worry about that. If you use, say, OpenStruct in some file, just add the require at the top. I find that I rarely have to require something. Most things are loaded already. Also, specs help. :)

Comment: Gems are loaded but classes from ruby stdlib are not. The problem here is that if I forget to require some file it doesn't break immediately, only if something changes in other files. In many other languages all required modules available only within the file that required them, it prevents such kind of errors.
So my question is what is the best way to not face such errors expect being extra alert every time you use a constant, because it doesn't really work.

Comment: @LevDenisov In this case, I suggest requiring things at boot time (application.rb or whatever). Also specs.